# Offline Server update

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, automatic-updates, microsoft

I have 3 machines that are completely shielded from the internet (Air gapped). I have a LARGE list of KBs from Microsoft that I need to download and install (Something like 200). I can NOT put the machine on the internet or connect it to WSUS or anything like that.  So I am required to download each KB manually and move them onto the server to install (The install part is fine, its downloading each one individually that is taking forever)

I've researched and because Microsoft has updated their download processes nothing seems to be straight forward and a lot of the older techniques are not relevant any longer.

Any idea how to just download all Microsoft updates available for Windows 2012 R2 in an offline mode?

Comment: You can use this to download the updates from an internet connected computer and package them for your isolated servers. - http://www.wsusoffline.net/

Comment: How about using a WSUS server connected to the internet to download the content and then packaging up all of the downloaded content and walk it over to the air gapped server.

Comment: Upgrade to server 2016 or 2019.  You can download the latest update and it will include the previous patches. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4043454/windows-10-windows-server-update-history

Comment: I agree with Joe. Upgrading saves you a lot of work in that regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While upgrading is a choice in the future thank you to Tim for WSUS offline builder.  Worked like a charm